# Invalid graphql request in Gentics Mesh with rest client

Tags: graphql, gentics-mesh

I get an error when executing a graph query using the MeshRestClient -

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Validation error of type InvalidFragmentType: Fragment cannot be spread here as objects of type Node can never be of type teaching @ 'node/children/elements'",
      "type": "ValidationError",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 288
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "message": "Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'fields' in type 'teaching' is undefined @ 'node/children/elements/fields'",
      "type": "ValidationError",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 315
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Although the same request works fine in Postman.

*Update*: I realized the client is executing the request against the `/api/v1` when using the client.
If I post the same query against `/api/v1` in Postman, I can reproduce the error.

I think if I can force the rest client to use `/api/v2`, it should work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/api/v2` with the `MeshRestClient` by setting the base path when creating the client:

```java
MeshRestClient.create(MeshRestClientConfig.newConfig()
    .setHost("demo.getmesh.io")
    .setPort(80)
    .setSsl(true)
    .setBasePath("/api/v2")
    .build());
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using the simple constructor and didn't see the baseUrl option. I appreciate all the work you guys have put into Mesh.